# What is the difference between if ($this-> _hasParam('name') and if($this->_getParam('name')), Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to check  in zend, whether a posted form  value 'name' contains  a value.For this i have used the following code

### one method

```
if ($this->_getPatram('name') != null ) {
  echo 'field name contains value';
} else {
  echo 'field name contains  null value';
}
```

### second method

```
if ($this->_hasParam('name')) {
 echo 'field name contains value';
} else {
  echo 'field name contains  null value';
}
```

### output , when submitting the form with the 'name'  field contains null value

### in first method

field name contains  null value  (result is correct)

### in second method

field name contains value (result is wrong)

So what is the difference between these two ? _hasParam and _getParam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->_hasParam('name')` returns true because `$this` **has** a parameter by the name `name`.

> field name contains value <s>(result is wrong)</s>

The result is correct. `$this` object in fact has a `name` field - The fact that its value happens to be `null` is not the concern of `_hasParam` function.

Use `_hasParam` to check if the object **has** a particular parameter or not and `_getParam` to **get** the value of that parameter.

For example, if you want to check if the submitted form has a property by the name `foo`, use `_hasParam("foo")`. To get the value of `foo`, use `_getParam("foo")`

Comment: so if use the second method for checking any of the  posted form values, it will return always true  irresptive of whether it contains value or not
let me  please know your comment

Answer (score 1):

`_hasParam()` returns whether the param exists, and `_getParam()` returns the actual value. The difference lies in the fact that there are several values that are considered equal to `null` even if they do exist, such as `0` or `''`'. Use `===` or `!==` to compare instead.

Comment: ok, i got , what you said.But if it consider '' as false, the result of  second method should come  as 'field name contains null value', but the answer comes is 'field name contains value'

Let me know please, why is happening so?